# Disinfecting a Supermicro IPMI Board

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, vulnerabilities

The IPMI board on one of our servers seems to have become infected - we were hit by the "password in the clear" vulnerability - and it seems to have allowed something to have infected by a bot that launched a DDoS attack.

Right now, we've taken it off-line, and know how to prevent it re-occuring. But...  how do I get rid of the infection?

Motherboard is a Supermicro X8SIE-LN4F
dmidecode reports these details about firmward and such
Supermicro X8SIE(-F)/X8SIE-LN4(F)/X8SI6-F v 1.0c 5/27/10
Does not seem to support the sh command

Given that the thing has its code in flash memory, and a limited instruction set - I'm wondering two things:
1. Where the bot code is actually stored
2. How to clear it out

Comment: And you know the IPMI board is actually infected... how?

Comment: Do you have a link to a resource that has information on this "password in the clear"  vulnerability ?

Comment: @Iain The guy who first discovered it [made a blog post about it here](http://blog.cari.net/carisirt-yet-another-bmc-vulnerability-and-some-added-extras/).  Always choose strong passwords - you never know when a crappy piece of code is going to expose them to the world.  That said, there's no evidence of actual, malware-infected hardware existing outside of the NSA.

Comment: Well, I'm 90% sure mine is infected.  Something was using it to launch a denial of service attack - and it was using ports that don't have services running (so it wasn't an amplification attack).  The questions come back to: if somebody or something logged into the IPMI board, where and how could it plant a bot, and how to get it out?

Comment: Don take this as wise cracking please, but as a gentle reminder for anyone else reading this: your IPMI board should be connected to an internal-only separate (V)LAN. These IPMI boards are not made with strong security in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The IPMI firmware of your board is ATEN-based. You can download the IPMI firmware image at the [Supermicro](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon3000/3400/X8SIE.cfm?IPMI=Y&TYP=LN4) website (it's named "SMT...").

You should use firmware version 3.15 (SMT_315.bin) or later and put IPMI behind a firewall or use the included firewall of the IPMI firmware. Check [this](http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Supermicro_IPMI_Security_Updates_July_2014) article for more details.

I assume that you have been affected by the NTP DDoS issue (if your current firmware is older than v3.13).